# JavaFX .getResource Method

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-14

Im new to Java and I keep getting an error in Intellij that it is having an issue with my start method.

I know the issue is because it doesn't like the path but I put the full path to the login.fxml file. I was following a tutorial but the path was exactly how mine is and the error went away.

Here is my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is my login.xml file code as well:

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: d32f2f;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.LoginController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="328.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;">
            <children>
                <JFXTextField fx:id="loginUserName" focusColor="#424242" layoutX="214.0" layoutY="67.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="272.0" promptText="Username" unFocusColor="#ff6659" />
                <JFXPasswordField fx:id="loginPassword" focusColor="#424242" layoutX="214.0" layoutY="137.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="272.0" promptText="Password" unFocusColor="#ff6659" />
                <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Login" textFill="#6f6767">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <JFXButton fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="269.0" layoutY="193.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="163.0" style="-fx-background-color: #424242;" text="Login" textFill="#fffefe" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="TO DO" textFill="#fcfafa">
            <font>
                <Font size="36.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <JFXButton fx:id="loginSignUpButton" layoutX="598.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="88.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9a0007;" text="Sign Up" textFill="WHITE" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and here is the error that im getting:

```
"Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:945)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/PaintConverter
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXTextField.java:266)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField.<init>(JFXTextField.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:558)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 25 more
Exception running application sample.Main
"
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Please post your `login.fxml` code

Comment: @vladwoguer Hi, I edited my post to add the login.fxml code

Comment: From your updated stack trace, your problem is here: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter`. Apparently you are using [JFoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/). Have you included the relevant details to your run configuration in Intellij? If your are using Maven, have you updated the `pom.xml`? If you are using java modules, have you updated the `module-info` file? Have you added relevant JARs to your CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0):

This part of the stack trace you posted indicates what the problem is.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   sample.controller.LoginController

From the *javadoc* for [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

> Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string
>   name using:
>
> - The forName method in class Class.
> - The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader.
> - The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.
>
> but no definition for the class with the specified name could be
>   found.

In other words file `sample\controller\LoginController.class` cannot be found.
Note that the above path is a relative path and it is relative to your app's working directory.
The working directory is the value of the `System` property "user.dir", as in

```
String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

So you can check why you are getting the exception.
Either there is no such file `LoginController.class` or it is in the wrong directory.

Comment: Hi, I did miss the LoginController class but I have fixed that and edited my post to include the most recent error. Fixing my class didnt fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it fixed your initial problem, but obviously not all your problems, so it did help you progress towards a solution.